# need assistance in look up the data between 2 tables

Tags: ms-access

I am having 2 tables in Microsoft access.

1st table name - details
2nd table name - code

in 1st table I have more than 15 columns, I need to insert one column after 10th column and rename the heading as "TYPE".
in 2nd table I have 5 column.

Common column in each table is Analysis code.

Table 1

```
+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+
| Test1 | test2 | Analysis code |   test4    |  test5  |
+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+
| ab    | dfd   | TON           | fddafd     | 212132  |
| ced   | fd    | SIN           | 2133       | dfd2fd1 |
| ef    | fdfd  | TON           | df2df1d31f | dfd3sa3 |
| gh    | dfd   | SIN           | dfd63      | c22     |
+-------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+
```

Table 2

```
+----------+---------------+----------+------------------------+
| sample 1 | Analysis code | sample 3 |          Type          |
+----------+---------------+----------+------------------------+
| 558825   | TON           | a        | Terminated on network  |
| 258c     | SIN           | b        | International network  |
| 5856c    | TOF           | c        | Terminated off network |
| a21c5b   | SMS           | d        | text message           |
+----------+---------------+----------+------------------------+
```

OUT PUT Table

```
+-------+-------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+---------+
| Test1 | test2 | Analysis code |         Type          |   test4    |  test5  |
+-------+-------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+---------+
| ab    | dfd   | TON           | Terminated on network | fddafd     | 212132  |
| ced   | fd    | SIN           | International network | 2133       | dfd2fd1 |
| ef    | fdfd  | TON           | Terminated on network | df2df1d31f | dfd3sa3 |
| gh    | dfd   | SIN           | International network | dfd63      | c22     |
+-------+-------+---------------+-----------------------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: Use formatting tools in order to make your post more "readable", and I do not even get what is your question.

Comment: http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the table1 and Table2 on the corresponding column. In your case "Analysis code"

a sample would be:

```
SELECT Test1, test2, [table1.Analysis code], table2.type .... rest
FROM table1 left join table2 on table1.[Analysis code] = tble2.[analysis code]
```

above SQL code will produce [somewhat]your expected output table. Having said that, please allow me to suggest, that you need to read more about SQL language and [relational databases]. will help you more!

Comment: on above example i have given only 5 columns for example but i have more than 20 columns, in that case do I need to update all the column names from table 1 by replacing rest on the above code right...

If you don't mind, can you please complete the above code without updating the rest over there, so that I will get some idea to do with my database in Access. Kindly do the needful. Thank you.